# Docker is not freeing memory from fail dockerfile builds

Tags: docker, memory-management, error-handling, dockerfile

[image]Why when I build an image from a docker-file and the build process fails, the memory used in the process is not being freed. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

And is not appearing as an image, because it fails to be created. Where, then the data is being accumulated?

Thank you, please If you need more information ask me.

UPDATE: Some zombie images starting appearing after some time.
UPDATE 2: Those zombie images and containers (?) somehow are the failed builds... if anyone has more information of what is going on, please share it with me.

Comment: How are collecting the information about memory? How much is it using? Can you put the information in the question

Comment: @Matt thank you for asking, I'm well aware of the used memory because I only have 5gb remaining so I can tell exactly how much it is spent. But anyway the question is already answered by yamenk below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker by default doesn't clean up useless images know as "dangling images". It provides however the following command to safely clean them.

```
docker image prune
```

Alternatively, you can pass the following argument to docker build to force cleanup.

```
  --force-rm                Always remove intermediate containers
```

Answer (score 5):

Run it:

```
docker builder prune --all -f
```

By default it make following: Remove all unused build cache from previous build process